# How to concatenate char *variable in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{    
    char *hi = "bye";
    char *bye = "abc";
    strcat(hi, bye);
    printf("%s\n", hi);


}
```

How would I concatenate these variables? Everything I'm trying crashes it

Comment: String literal constant not modifiable...

Answer (score 2):

You can't. String literals are non-modifiable.

You can if you make a copy out of it which is modifiable. Here the `char` array is initialized with the content of the string literal.

```
char hi[10]="bye";
...
```

This will work.

In your case by using `strcat` on string literal you are invoking undefined behavior.

From [6.4.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7)

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. *If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined*.

Also from [J2: Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) listings from standard

> The program attempts to modify a string literal

---

Note that even if string literal was modifiable then also it would not be a defined behavior to concatenate strings. While concatenating strings make sure the string on which you are concatenating has enough space - otherwise it would try to write beyond the char array which itself will invoke undefined behavior. One thing you can see for yourself on the light of what I said in this paragraph (char array initialized with string literal's value),

```
char hi[]="bye";
```

Then using `strcat` would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: are you sure.. because he doing `strcat` ??

Comment: @ThiruShetty.: Yes I am sure.

Comment: @ThiruShettt Why not?

Comment: @ThiruShetty, string literal are put in `.rodata`, a read only section and mapped to proces as a 'read only data', in which case any attempt to write will cause issue.

Comment: Yes he is right. because it's only 3 characters  appending

Comment: @NishanthShetty that is **not** the reason. On some systems strings might not be mapped as read only. The reason is that standard disallows you from doing that.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya, okay. Can you tell me which systems and what is the reason to not to map it as a read only. I thought it will be same as code text, read only.

Comment: @NishanthShetty memory constrained MCUs or MCUs that don't have a MMU.

Answer (score 1):

String literal is **immutable**. Any attempt to modify it invokes *undefined behavior*.

You'll be able to modify it if you store the target string in an array:

```
int main()
{    
    char hi[10] = "bye";
    char *bye = "abc";
    strcat(hi, bye);
    printf("%s\n", hi);
}
```

Quoting C standard draft N1570, section 6.4.5/7:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

See more at [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164194/5958455)