# How to append a char var[] to a char ? C

Tags: c

```
char hi[10] = "bye";
char a = 'a';
strcat(hi, a);
```

Like the example above. How would I do this in C? Is there a more general string I cant let hi be?

Comment: `hi[strlen(hi)] = a;`

Comment: Avoid creating multiple accounts to ask similar questions [How to concatenate char *variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576594/how-to-concatenate-char-variable-in-c)

Comment: @Keine Lust, No, you also need to "move" the NUL

Comment: @ikegami, move what? the array is initialized (filled) with zeroes, there is nothing to move.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a `char` type while `strcat` expects it's both arguments of type `char *`. To append the char to an array of characters you can do this

```
int index = strlen(hi);
if(index < sizeof(hi)-1)
    hi[index] = a;
```

Note that in this particular case the initializer will initialize the first three elements of `hi` to `b`, `y` and `e` respectively. The rest of the elements will be initialized to `0`. Therefore you do not need to take care of the null termination of the array after appending each character to it. But in general you have to take care of that.

```
int index = strlen(hi);
if(index < sizeof(hi)-1){
    hi[index] = a;
    hi[index+1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: And in general, one then needs to add `hi[index+1] = '\0';` — though in the question's context, where the array has been initialized with trailing zeros, it is not actually crucial.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Yes agreed but as you pointed out it is not necessary in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcat(hi, (char[]){a,0});
```

This would append the `a`.

Or you can do this

```
char s[]={a,0};
strcat(hi,s);
```

Or simply

```
   #define MAXLEN 10
   ...
   size_t len = strlen(hi);
   if( len+1 <= MAXLEN-1)
      hi[len]=a,hi[len+1]=0;
   else
     // throw error.
```

In your case `hi[len+1]=0` is not required as it is already filled with `\0`. Also as mentioned by Serge that you can use simply used the string literal as the second parameter to the `strcat` function.

```
strcat(hi,"a");
```

There is a subtle difference in this two as mentioned by [Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) again, that string literals are `const` but the compound literals are not.

Comment: The *compound literal* may be way over his head in this case.... (but a good use of it)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Hm..I am afraid it is so...

Comment: It could be written as `strcat(hi, "a");`. The string litteral is const when your *compound literal* is not, but it does not matter here (and IMHO is more readable for a beginner).

Comment: @SergeBallesta.: Nice point...and yes it matters to me. Thanks that you mentioned. Sorry for th elate reply.